# How to determine if an Android device has GPU from code?

Tags: android, gpu

I want to know if an Android device has GPU or not, is there any way to determine that from code? I've looked into `cpufeatures.h` in NDK but there seems not to be anything regarding GPU

Comment: All Android devices have a GPU, AFAIK.

Comment: Could you, please, tell me the source of this information? I'm pretty sure my HTC Wildfire doesn't have one.

Comment: I am the source of this information. Apparently I am mistaken, though I feel very confident that the *vast* majority of Android devices have GPUs. Your Wildfire is an outlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the trick,

```
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager
                .getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
        final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;

    if (supportsEs2) {
        Log.i("JO", "configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion:"
                + configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion + "supportsEs2:"
                + supportsEs2);
        // Request an OpenGL ES 2.0 compatible context.
        myGlsurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        // Set the renderer to our demo renderer, defined below.
        myRenderer = new MyRenderer(this, myGlsurfaceView);
```